# Magento 2 + Get customer default billing address in custom module js

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, customer-address

Is there any way I can get a customer default billing address in custom js ?

```
var defaultBillingAddresses = addressList().filter(function (address) {
                console.log(address.getType());
                return  address.getType() == 'customer-address' && address.isDefaultBilling();
            });
```

Above is mine code with inject

```
'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list'
```

but it's not retrieving any thing.

Comment: have you tried using customerData with customer.js ?

Comment: yes, but can you clarify more your point

Answer (score 1):

not sure, I haven't tried this code.

```
var customerData = {};
if (isLoggedIn()) {
    customerData = window.customerData;
} else {
    customerData = {};
}

cust_addresses = this.customerData.addresses;
// user for each for addresses
if(cust_addresses[addressId]['default_billing'] == 1)
{
//write your code here.
}
```

hope this will help.

Comment: not working....!